# How to filter a featurecollection to an object that can be used with path.bounds()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I’ve been trying to make a map with a zoom to bounding box functionality, based on this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675.

But for municipalities with islands, the zoom goes to the bounding box of the selected landmass instead of the bounding box of the municipality.

I figured out that in my data, municipalities with several areas separated by water consist of multiple polygons with the same nametag instead of a single multipolygon as in Mike Bostocks example above.

I managed to fix the issue for filling in the areas, so the error becomes even more obvious if you click on one of the small islands, but I cannot figure out how to properly zoom to the bounding box of the municipality instead of the land area.

I tried looking for different ways to filter or subset a featurecollection based on the areanames but my solutions all end up giving me a wrong data type, or a bounding box from -infinity to infinity.

To sum up, the intended behaviour is for the zoom to go to the bounding box of the highlighted area instead of the selected landmass.

Here is my map so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/iywWsM9RLs7UzI40q66M?p=preview

I slowed down the zoom a bit so the it’s easier to spot the error, I hope it’s not too annoying.

And here is the code piece where i suspect things are going wrong.

```
function clicked(d) {

  if (d.properties.KOMNAVN == kommune) return reset();
  d3.selectAll("path")
    .attr("fill", "teal");

  kommune = d.properties.KOMNAVN;

  var bounds = path.bounds(d),
    dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
    dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
    x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
    y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
    scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(zoomExtent, 0.95 / Math.max(dx / w, dy / h))),
    translate = [w / 2 - scale * x, h / 2 - scale * y];

  svg.transition()
    .duration(4000)
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(translate[0], translate[1]).scale(scale));

  d3.selectAll("path").filter(function(d) {
      return d.properties.KOMNAVN == kommune
    })
    .attr("fill", "darkred");

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.bounds` (or `projection.fitSize` and `projection.fitExtent`) for that matter, requires a a geojson object, which can be a feature collection. Feeding this function an array will cause issues.

A feature collection looks like:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features": features
}
```

where features is an array of feature types.

You have a a feature collection for your dataset, and you can filter the features:

```
var filteredFeatures = data.features.filter(function(feature) {
    return feature.properties.property == criteria
})
```

Then you can create a new feature collection with these filtered features. In your case this might look like:

```
  var filteredFeatures = json.features.filter(function(feature) {
    return feature.properties.KOMNAVN == d.properties.KOMNAVN;
  })

  var filteredFeatureCollection = {
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":filteredFeatures
  }
```

No you can send this new feature collection to path.bounds.

Note that for your example I've moved the click function into the call back function for d3.json so that the scope of the `json` variable covers the click function.

Here's an [updated plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/cBCX2z6ZxBKn4RbDDpJI?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot, solution is as simple as I was hoping? As for the last bit, what's the reasoning behind moving the click function?

Comment: The `json` variable scope didn't extend to the click function, since `json` is only defined within the callback function. Not moving the function results in an error saying `json` is not defined. There are other ways to handle that, but this was easiest.

Comment: Right ok, I think I'll have to play around with that a bit, thanks again for the insight.